# How to change jboss timezone?Java property is not working

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

it seems the jboss is using dates as UTC, I verified this by simply doing:

```
log.info(new Date());
```

And I get the UTC time.

So, in order to change it I added to standalone.conf the following property:

```
-Duser.timezone=Europe/Rome
```

But it's still not working!
Any other idea?

Comment: which mode are you using for running jboss?

Comment: I'm using the standalone mode

Comment: share how are you adding above property in standalone.conf file? share lines in that file and also share how are you starting the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just complementing Panagiotis answer:

```
<system-properties>
        <property name="user.timezone" value="GMT"/>
</system-properties>
```

### For Standalone

Linux/Unix: add to the user.timezone system property in standalone.conf 
  Microsoft: same thing but on standalone.conf.bat file.

### Cli command to change the timezone

Or even set as JVM parameter directly:

./standalone.sh -Duser.timezone=UTC

### To verify

/core-service=platform-mbean/type=runtime:read-attribute(name=system-properties)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the `user.timezone` as a system property in `standalone.conf` :

```
.
.
.
    <system-properties>
        <property name="user.timezone" value="GMT+03:00"/>
    </system-properties>
.
.
.
```

Comment: mmm...mine is not an xml but a plain text conf file

Comment: Answer given is for domain mode not for standalone mode as requested by user